# How to add logo to rss feed

Tags: rss

I came across this function to add image to rss feed. However, I keep getting lots of syntax errors.

```
/* Add RSS Logo */

function addRssImage() {
  echo "<image>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <url>" . get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/images/logo.png</url>
    <link>" . get_bloginfo('url') ."</link>
    <width>300</width>
    <height>60</height>
    <description>MyDomain.com</description>
    </image>";
add_action('rss2_head', 'addRssImage');
/* End RSS Logo */
```

Comment: What are those errors? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705224/rss-2-0-image-in-an-item

Comment: @feeela, the question is about adding an image to the head of the entire feed. The link you shared is about added images to the individual posts in the feed body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted is missing an ending `}`

here is a fixed and tested version of that code, so if you still get errors they are coming from another place

```
function addRssImage() {
  echo "<image>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <url>" . get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/images/logo.png</url>
    <link>" . get_bloginfo('url') ."</link>
    <width>300</width>
    <height>60</height>
    <description>MyDomain.com</description>
    </image>";
}
add_action('rss2_head', 'addRssImage');
```

Comment: Brilliant.. need to pay more attention to php scripts. Thanks a ton